# Scenario Outline Examples reference to the defined variable is lost when moving from version 1.2.0 of karate to version 1.3.0

Tags: karate

Reference to the defined variable is lost when moving from version 1.2.0 of karate to version 1.3.0.
Please give a solution to fix this.

```
@e-invoice
Feature: With Space user, send e-invoice standing order agreement to bank as an ADD action (constraint checks)

  Background:
    * url baseUrl
    * configure ssl = true
    * callonce read('classpath:e_invoice_adapter/space/e-invoice-space-liveness.feature')
    * call read('classpath:utils/common.feature')
    * def testData = read('classpath:e_invoice_adapter/space/soa/test_data/space_send_e_invoice_soa_validation.csv')
    * def getDbConnection = callonce read('classpath:utils/connectDB.feature@getDbConnectionInfo')
    * def db = getDbConnection.db

    Scenario Outline: Space user sends an e-invoice soa, <scenarioName>
      * def arrayIndex = function(x, index){ return index == __num}
      * copy eInvoiceTestData = karate.filter(testData, arrayIndex)
      * print eInvoiceTestData
      * def sendEInvoiceSoaSpace = call read('classpath:e_invoice_adapter/space/soa/core/send-e-invoice-soa-validation-process.feature') eInvoiceTestData
      * print eInvoiceTestData
      Examples:
        |testData|

    @ignore
    Scenario: Debugging 1 scenario - user sends an e-invoice soa
      * def arrayIndex = function(x, index){ return index == 36}
      * copy eInvoiceTestData = karate.filter(testData, arrayIndex)
      * print eInvoiceTestData
      * def sendEInvoiceSoaSpace = call read('classpath:e_invoice_adapter/space/soa/core/send-e-invoice-soa-validation-process.feature') eInvoiceTestData
      * print eInvoiceTestData
```

```
@ignore
Feature:Send e-invoice standing order agreement with Space user process

  Background:

  Scenario Outline:
    * def eInvoiceTestData = __arg
    * def soaRequest = {"input": {"agreement": {}}}
    Given eval if ('<removeParameter>' != 'x') karate.remove('soaRequest', '<removeParameter>')
    Given eval if (<systemId> != 'x') karate.set('soaRequest', 'input.agreement.systemId', <systemId>)
    Given eval if ('<sellerRegistrationNumber>' != 'x') karate.set('soaRequest', 'input.agreement.sellerRegistrationNumber', '<sellerRegistrationNumber>')
    Given eval if (<serviceId> != 'x') karate.set('soaRequest', 'input.agreement.serviceId', <serviceId>)
    Given eval if ('<payerIban>' != 'x') karate.set('soaRequest', 'input.agreement.payerIban', '<payerIban>')
    Given eval if ('<payerCode>' != 'x') karate.set('soaRequest', 'input.agreement.payerCode', '<payerCode>')
    Given eval if ('<payerName>' != 'x') karate.set('soaRequest', 'input.agreement.payerName', '<payerName>')
    Given eval if ('<paymentLimit>' != 'x') karate.set('soaRequest', 'input.agreement.paymentLimit', <paymentLimit>)
    Given eval if ('<monthlyLimit>' != 'x') karate.set('soaRequest', 'input.agreement.monthlyLimit', <monthlyLimit>)
    Given eval if ('<startDate>' != 'x') karate.set('soaRequest', 'input.agreement.startDate', <startDate>)
    Given eval if ('<endDate>' != 'x') karate.set('soaRequest', 'input.agreement.endDate', <endDate>)
    Given eval if ('<signingDate>' != 'x') karate.set('soaRequest', 'input.agreement.signingDate', <signingDate>)
    * print soaRequest
    * set eInvoiceTestData.postSOA.request =  soaRequest

    * def sendEInvoiceSoa = call read('classpath:e_invoice_adapter/space/soa/reuse-soa.feature@spaceSoaSend') eInvoiceTestData
    * set eInvoiceTestData.postSOA.requestUri = sendEInvoiceSoa.requestUri
    * set eInvoiceTestData.postSOA.response = sendEInvoiceSoa.response
    * print sendEInvoiceSoa.response
    * def expectedResponse = read('classpath:e_invoice_adapter/space/soa/response/validation/<expectedResponse>')
    * match sendEInvoiceSoa.response == expectedResponse

    Examples:
      |eInvoiceTestData|
```

[report with karate 1.3.0 for one scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQKac.png)

[report with karate 1.3.0 for scenario outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwe59.png)

Karate version 1.2.0 and earlier worked perfectly for me.

I hope version 1.3 performs no worse than 1.2. How to do it?

[report with karate 1.2.0 for one scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5y8sU.png)

[report with karate 1.2.0 for scenario outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpUOK.png)

[Structure I used to test the REST API.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEHkU.png)

Comment: this is too long for me to read and understand so I request you to follow this process, create the simplest possible example and file an issue: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - just so you know, we spend months releasing RC versions asking users to submit feedback to avoid surprises like this

Comment: Added project with possibility to repeat the issue https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2180